# Manjarno-i3 config location

Tags: manjaro, i3

I recently started using Manjarno-i3 edition. I noticed there is no i3 config file at the lcoation `~/.config/i3/config` which is where I always found the default file on ubuntu.

Does anyone know where I can find the default config file so I can make some changes?

Answer (score 2):

If there is indeed already a user configuration file it may be at `~/.i3/config` instead of `~/.config/i3/config`. If there is none, you should be able to create one with `i3-config-wizard` or you can just copy `/etc/i3/config` (or possibly `/etc/xdg/i3/config`).

According `man 1 i3` `i3` looks in the following places - and in that order - for a configuration file:

1. `~/.config/i3/config` (or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/i3/config` if set)
2. `/etc/xdg/i3/config` (or `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/i3/config` if set)
3. `~/.i3/config`
4. `/etc/i3/config`

`i3` takes the first configuration file it finds. Multiple configuration files are *not* merged. It is also possible to specify a configuration file with the option `-c FILE`.

Comment: Do you know if I can just write a few additions in a small config file and have that overlay on the defaults? btw will mark checked after I test later.

Comment: Not really. *i3* does have defaults for window layouts, decorations and and colors, so you do not have to set them. *But* AFAIK there are no built in defaults for the key bindings and without those *i3* is practically unusable. Also, as I said *i3* will only load one configuration file, so if you want to keep bindings or any other settings from the default configuration file, you will have to copy them.